# C# ThreadPool in window services vs EXE

Tags: c#, sockets, threadpool, exe

I have a window services hosting a TCP/IP connections server and dealing with multiple connections coming in and out.

There is a logic to recognize the `socket.BeginAccept(callback, null)` data and when it is detected a complete package, it will raise and event for another handler.

For the handler part, there is a factory method that generate the handler.
Below is the snippet for code.

```
var handler = _handlerFactory.Create(socket, data);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => handler.HandleJsonData(data));
```

After running this in window service mode  for 3 hours, the service thread counts will suddenly spike from 40 to 1020++, which hit the maximum thread count, then the service no longer start responding.

However, if I use the exactly the same code, host the server in EXE form, it has no issue.
Below is the code used for hosting in EXE.

```
var hostingServer = new HostingServer();
hostingServer.Start();
```

Below is the hosting code used for running in window service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var hostingServer = new HostingServer();
    hostingServer.Start();
}
```

Until now, I still can't figure it out why running the same code in EXE form have no problem, but it have problem when using window service. Anyone have the same problem before?

Comment: Remember that a service by default is running as the machine not as you. THis can lead to all sorts of odd behavior (permissions on resources, things configured in the registry,...)

Comment: Thanks @pm100, I'll try on running the service with admin account and give it a shoot. 
PS: The thread count is get from **Resource Monitor**, when it happens, the thread count will grown like 100+ per seconds.

Comment: Do you pop unnecessary threads or do you keep them in your thread pool??

Comment: @Blaatz0r I didn't pop any threads, I'm leaving it to the thread pool to handle it.